# Task.WhenAll - When to use this

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I know [Task.WaitAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695(v=vs.110).aspx)(Task1,Task2) waits for all of the provided Task objects to complete execution.

What is Task.WhenAll used for?

[Task.WhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374(v=vs.110).aspx) in MSDN says

> Creates a task that will complete when all of the supplied tasks have
>   completed.

What is the real world scenario where once can apply Task.WhenAll()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WaitAll` is a `void` function that lets your code wait for completion of multiple tasks right away, at the time when you call it.

`WhenAll`, on the other hand, produces a `Task` that will wait for other tasks when it is its time to run. For example, if you are building a `Task` that needs to initialize a couple of things, and then run some computation, you can do it like this:

```
var initThenRun = Task
    .WhenAll(initTask1, initTask2, initTask3)
    .ContinueWith(computationTask);
```

Now the `initThenRun` task will run the three initialization tasks, wait for all of them to complete, and only then proceed to the `computationTask`.

Comment: So what difference with `Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new Task[]{initTask1, initTask2, initTask3}, computationTask)`

Comment: @KevinBui Since this is a different question, consider asking it as a question, not as a comment. This would give your question more visibility, potentially leading to much better answers.

Answer (score 8):

`WaitAll` blocks the calling thread while `WhenAll` provides a promise task that you can use to **asynchronously** wait using `async-await` without wasting up a thread in the meantime:

```
async Task ProcessAsync()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(DownloadAsync(), IntializeParserAsync(),...);
}
```

You should use `WhenAll` wherever you want to wait without having to block a thread, which improves scalability. (read: almost anywhere you can)